# Crashlytics REST API for Closing Issues

Tags: google-fabric

Are there any REST APIs from Crashlytics that could be used to close issues, comment issues etc...? Specifically they're servicing/managing functions of the platform rather than the ones for creating Issues for crashes.

I'm planning on adding a webhook on our internal git server (Gogs) that would parse commit messages looking for certain tag (like "Closes FCI123", FCI meaning Fabric Crashlytics Issue and after it is the issue number) and close and comment issues automatically in order to keep things in sync across the tools we're using. Sort of automating certain tasks and increasing productivity.

Comment: @mike-bonnell would appreciate your help here, or are there other means for the above scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Crashlytics doesn't currently have a public API.